# Redisplaying a form with fields filled in

Tags: forms, contacts, verification

I need a bit of help with redisplaying a form.

Basically, currently a user will fill out my contact form, the form and it's contents are passed to my verification page, and if the recaptcha was entered correctly it goes to a Thank You page.

When the recaptcha is entered INCORRECTLY, I want to redisplay the contact form with the fields already filled out. How do I do this? (As you'll see below, it currently goes to google on incorrect captcha)

Here is my verification code. Any help would be great:

```
<?php require('sbsquared.class.php'); ?>
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "myprivatekey";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");  <--- this is the bit that I want to redisplay the form with fields already filled out.
  } else {

    $sb = New SBSquared;

    $name = $_POST['FullName'];
    $post_keys = array_keys($_POST);
    $my_db_string = "<table>";
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    foreach($post_keys as $field)
    {
        if($_POST[$field] != "" && $field != "submit_y" && $field != "submit_x" && $field != "submit_x")
        {

            $my_db_string .= "<tr><td><b>".$field.":</b></td><td>";
            if($field == "Email")
            {
                $my_db_string .= '<a href = "mailto:'.$_POST['Email'].'">'.$_POST['Email'].'</a>';
            }
            else
            {
                $my_db_string .= $_POST[$field];
            }

            $my_db_string .= "</td></tr>";

        }
    }

    $my_db_string .= "<tr><td><b>IP ADDRESS LOGGED: </b></td><td>".$ip_address."</td></tr>";

    $my_db_string .= "</table>";

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() != 1)
    {
        $my_db_string = addslashes($my_db_string);
        $name = addslashes($name);
    }

    $conn = $sb->openConnection();
    $dts = time();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contact_queries` VALUES ('', '$name', '$my_db_string', 'n/a', 0, $dts)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

$content = '<div id="main_middle">';

$content .= '<span class="title">'.$sb->dt('Contact').'</span>
<p>'.$sb->dt('Thank you for your enquiry. We will contact you shortly.').'</p>


</div>';

// admin auto email.
        $dts = date("d.m.y h:ia", time());
        $admin_content = "New contact query at $dts";
        $admin_content .= "\n\n--\n\n \r\n\r\n";
        mail("email address", 'NOTIFICATION: new query', $admin_content, 'From: email address');
        $FILE=fopen("./log/auto-contact.txt","a");
        fwrite($FILE, $admin_content);
        fclose($FILE);

echo pageHeader($sb);
echo pageContent($sb, $content);
echo pageFooter($sb);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already answered this for yourself, but if not you can set ReCaptcha to validate prior to submitting the form, much the same as HTML5 validation. It just won't let the user submit until the Captcha is correct. Now, I don't know if it will refresh the captcha if it is incorrect but most of the time I see people putting it into an iFrame so it doesn't refresh the page when refreshing the captcha.

As an alternative, you can use sessions to keep the data filled in.